# mention or tag people on mobile web pages

Tags: support, comments, notifications, mobile-web, display-names

On the main web site page I can type `@` followed by first few characters of op name to tag him to comment. Is there a similar feature for web pages which render for mobile.

Comment: Are you asking if the notification feature works on Mobile?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

It doesn't give the Gen-U-Wine SuperAwesomeUserIdentifier PopupSheet in the mobile site, **but** it *still* works.

Note that this will make typing in usernames with non-ASCII characters very hard, but **remember**, to ping a user:

- You only need the first 3 characters minimum
- If there are multiple users in a comment thread with similar usernames, you just need to use enough characters of the username to single out the user.

For example, if Yannis was in a comment thread and I wanted to ping him, but another user called Yanny was also in the thread, I would need to use @Yanni to single out Yannis.

Comment: Is it case-sensitive? The "you only need a prefix" note is so key, making the feature usable for me.